# Degree: Polynomial Class (Odd Cases for User Input Expected)

Tags: c++, polynomial-math

I have a polynomial class that prompts the user to enter values to be put into a vector of integers (`vector<int> vect_poly`). I'm trying to think of a way to detect the degree of the polynomial for cases where the user does something like this in the while loop:

0↵0↵0↵0↵4↵0↵0↵0↵0 ← x^4 (degree=4)

(OR)

0↵0↵0↵0↵0↵0↵0↵0↵0 ← (degree=0)

(OR)

4↵0↵0↵0↵0↵0↵0↵0↵0 ← x^0 (degree=0)

(OR)

0↵0↵0↵0↵0↵0↵0↵0↵4 ← x^8 (degree=8)

I'm really just looking for a slick algorithm.

---

What about this:

```
 int degree()
 {
 int d = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
       if ( coef[i] != 0 ) d = i;
          return d;
 }
```

Comment: ↵ means that the user presses enter?

Comment: What is your current algorithm?

Comment: When I say "slick" I mean like how I see that `int max(int a, int b){return a > b ? a : b;}` is a slick max function. Short, concise, etc.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The user presses enter is what that symbol means.

Comment: I just did `return vect_poly.size()-1`, but this does not take into account these special cases.

Comment: Is there a binary tree application for this problem here?

Comment: I'm seeking a lastness detection algorithm that is short and memory smart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local variable to keep track of the max, and each time the user presses enter, you compare their input to the current max value.

```
int max=0;
while(1)
{
    int input=0;
    std::cin>>input;
    if(input>max)
    {
        max=input;
    }
}
```

Of course with some breakout condition so the loop doesn't run forever. You could try to mess with the ternary operator at the if statement, but I see little value in that.

EDIT: if you want to know the last set value (ie degree) of a previously generated but essentially random vector as quickly as possible, run a loop like this:

```
int max=0;
for(int k= myvec.size()-1; k>=0; k--)
{
    if(myvec[k]>0)
    {
         max=k;
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `0>0`?

Comment: 0>0 returns false (which equals zero/NULL). The degree data would be contained by the max variable.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1. Simply copy the input into the vector, then search for the last non-zero and truncate the vector after that.
2. Copy input into a temporary vector, and each time a non-zero is entered, move-append the temporary vector to `vect_poly`, like this:

   ```
   std::vector<int> temp;
   int n;
   while (std::cin >> n) {
     temp.push_back(n);
     if (n != 0) {
       vect_poly.insert(vect_poly.end(), temp.begin(), temp.end());
       temp.clear();
     }
   }
   ```

   That way, you get everything except the trailing zero sequence in `vect_poly`.

**EDIT**

3. You can also keep the `0`s in a counter:

```
int n;
size_t zeroes = 0;
while (std::cin >> n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    ++zeroes;
  } else {
    vect_poly.insert(vect_poly.end(), zeroes, 0);
    vect_poly.push_back(n);
    zeroes = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Memory-wise, I'd say this is perhaps not optimal. What do you think?

Comment: @LoieBenedicte I've added a less memory-consuming option

Answer (score 0):

If u have this vector where user have enter the value of coefficient, you can traverse the vector from index 0 to the last element (Assuming user will enter the value of coefficient in correct order), and just save the value of last index whose value is not zero.

```
 int degreeOfPolynomial=0;
 for(int i=0 ; i < vect_poly.size() ; i++)
 {
   if(vect_poly[i] != 0)
   degreeOfPolynomial = i;
 }
```

After execution of above part of code, **degreeOfPolynomial** will store right value of degree of polynomial.

Comment: I know that some processes are faster than others, perhaps this task can be done in a faster way using theory from mathematics or logic. I am for some reason bent on it being done faster via a binary-tree approach.

Comment: @LoieBenedicte : if this post answer your question, can u please accept this answer by clicking check mark?

Comment: as for efficiency, i believe there is no way other than traversing whole vector to know for sure the degree of polynomial. Or else u can avoid traversing by monitoring degree of polynomial using same logic when user entering value into vector

Answer (score 0):

Why not just keep track of it?

```
std::vector<int> polynomial;
int degree = 0;
int inputs = 0;
int coefficient;
while (std::cin >> coefficient)
{
    polynomial.push_back(coefficient);
    if (coefficient != 0)
    {
       degree = inputs;
    }
    inputs++;
}
```